# How do I use .Value to get cell value and search for another cell w same value?

Tags: excel, vba, find

So I am computing a date 18 months out from start date then deleting every column after 18 months.

E2 is where I currently store the calculated 18 months out value.
So this week, 18 months out is 7/24/2023.. I need this to search for 7/24/2023 in row 1, find it, then delete every column after.

```
Range(Cells(1, Range("1:1").Find(What:=Range("E2").Value.Column + 1), 
_ Cells(1, Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column)).EntireColumn.Delete
```

Comment: What the problem you're having with that code?

Comment: It's just coming up in red. Compile error

Comment: `What:=Range("E2").Value` not sure what the `.Column + 1` is for but that's not valid syntax.

Comment: Nevermind, fixed the compile error. Now getting an error saying object required

Comment: The .Column + 1 is to find the column after and delete

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your +1 is in the wrong place

When using find() it's best to check you got a match:

```vb
Dim f as Range, ws as Worksheet

set ws = Activesheet
Set f = ws.Rows(1).Find(What:=ws.Range("E2").Value)
If Not f Is Nothing then
    ws.Range(f.Offset(0, 1), ws.Cells(1, ws.Columns.count).End(xlToLeft)).EntireColumn.Delete
End if
```